# MVC 5 Content Disposition errors in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, model-view-controller

I would like to display the user manual of the system as pdf in the browser.

The following code works fine in IE9 but not

Chrome - Error duplicate errors received from server

Firefox - Corrupted content error

The MVC 5 code ( I think is adding duplicate headers which IE can handle)

Just wondering is there any way this will work with all browsers?

```
public FileResult UserManual()
    {
        var FileName = "user-manual.pdf";
        var cd = new ContentDisposition
        {
            Inline = true,
            FileName = FileName
        };
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "App_Data/";
        return File(path + FileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, FileName);

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old but I got into the same issue today.

If you add a "Content-Disposition" header then do not return File with the "FileName" argument added

Check this:

```
if (myFile.IsInlineContent()) // Evaluate the content type to check if the file can be shown in the browser
{
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", $"inline; myFile.Filename}");
    return File(myFile.Path, myFile.Type); // return without filename argument
} 
// if not, treat it as a regular download
return File(myFile.Path, myFile.Type, myFile.Filename); // return with filename argument
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

In order to show the file in the browser, do not provide the file name as the third parameter to the File method in your return statement. This forces a content-disposition of attachment behind the scenes. As such, your code should result in an invalid response with an ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION error.